# Is there any way to disable cache for frontend price block

Tags: magento2, price, frontend, cache

Is there any way for disabling price caching in magento frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `cacheable=false` to blocks which are part of a page rendering is not a good idea as the whole page will be rendered **as uncached**. See [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html):

> Do not configure content pages (i.e., catalog, product, and CMS pages)
> to be uncacheable. Doing so has an adverse affect on performance.

Better way is to fetch the prices via Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable cache using XML. Please follow the below steps:

1. open catalog_product_prices.xml.
2. Replace the code below:

From:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">`

To:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices" cacheable="false">`

After then flush the cache and check it working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Copy 'catalog_product_prices.xml' from

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`

into your theme

`app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`.

Update the below code:

From:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">`

To:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices" cacheable="false">`

After then run below command:

`bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f`

Still, if you have an issue please let us know.